# C# Linq Merging Dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Can any one pls help me explaining the below lines

> a.Concat(b).GroupBy(p => p.Key).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g =>
>   g.Last().Value);

```
Dictionary<string, string> a = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> b = new Dictionary<string, string>();

a.Add("1", "a");
a.Add("2", "a");
a.Add("4", "a");
a.Add("6", "a");
a.Add("7", "a");

b.Add("2", "sdfsdd");
b.Add("3", "dfvdfvd");
b.Add("4", "sdfdss");
```

As I am new to "linq" I am not able to understand this piece of code. I just understood that it concatenates the value of two dictionaries and the values of the second dictionary replaces the value in first but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This concatenates the two dictionaries, as you said.

```
a.Concat(b)
```

Then, from the concatenated list, we group the values based on the dictionary keys

```
.GroupBy(p => p.Key)
```

Finally, we export the data as a dictionary, using the existing key as the key in the exported dictionary

```
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
```

and the last value that matches that key as the value. The other values in the group are ignored.

```
g => g.Last().Value);
```

The expressions used in the methods, e.g. `p => p.Key`, in this case roughly mean "Of the object type in the list before, use it using the variable name `p`, and then get the value from the expression after the `=>`"

Hope this helps you to understand what it's doing. It took me a while to get my head round linq when I first started with it too.

Answer (score 0):

`a.Concat(b)` returns `IEnumerable` of `KeyValuePair<string, string>` 
then you group by key with `GroupBy(p => p.Key)`, it returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>>`, which is basically enumerable of groups. Each group has a key and list of key value pairs.
And the most important part:
`ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Last().Value);`
it creates a dictionary from enumerable. 

The first lambda, `g => g.Key`, selects dictionary key taking it from `IGrouping`. 
The second lambda, `g => g.Last().Value`, takes the last element of a group using `Last` method, thus if you a collision between first and second dictionary, element from second one will be taken as value.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a `Dictionary<key, value>` can be thought of as a collection of pairs:  (regardless of how the data is actually stored internally).  In C#-speak, think of the `Dictionary` as a collection of `KeyValuePair<key, value>` instances.  What the call to `Concat` does is unpack the contents of the two `Dictionary` instances as two `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<key, value>>` instances and simply joins the two into a single `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<key, value>>`.

However, for merging two `Dictionary` instances, there wouldn't be duplicate keys and the output of `Concat` may contain duplicate key values.  Therefore, the items in the `Concat` result should be grouped by the key value.  This is what `GroupBy` does - it selects the `key` from each `KeyValuePair` and, if it's new, a new group entry is created with the group key set to the `KeyValuePair` key.  The group value is a collection which would contain only the value from the `KeyValuePair`.  If the key is not new then the value from the `KeyValuePair` is added to the collection of the existing group.

The last part - `ToDictionary` is what decides which `Dictionary`'s value wins when both `Dictionary`'s contain a given key value.  In this case, it's the value from `b` because the items from `a` appear first in the `Concat` result and `ToDictionary` is selecting the last element in each group.  If the merge needed to keep the value from `a` then the call to `Last` in `ToDictionary` would be replaced by a call to `First`.  And the merged `Dictionary` does not strictly speaking have to be of the same type as the input `Dictionary`'s.  It could be a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>` instead, keeping all values for each key by calling

`GroupBy(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(val => val.Value))`

Answer (score -1):

> a.Concat(b).GroupBy(p => p.Key).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g =>
>   g.Last().Value);

it contains three extension method which concatenates `a` and `b` and returns new dictionary:

1. `Enumerable.Concat<TSource>` Method:
   Concatenates two sequences. `TSource` is the type of the elements of the input sequences. in your dictionary it refers to `KeyValuePaird<string,string>` type.
2. `Enumerable.GroupBy<TSource, TKey>` Method:
   Groups the elements of a sequence according to a specified key selector function. `TSource` is the type of the elements of source. again in here is `KeyValuePaird<string,string>` type. and the `TKey` is the type of the key returned by `keySelector`.
3. `ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Last().Value)` :
   Creates a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` from an `IEnumerable<T>` according to a specified key selector function.

actually this method convert any IEnumerable to Dictionary type, it gives two parameters Key and Value which the key should be unique.

Comment: pls understand my question bro i just want a clear explanation of the code that is highlighted above